# datagridview cell is nothing after data is deleted

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a function that automatically tallies some cells in a data grid and display the result every time a user enters a value in then. It works, however when data is deleted, the cell where the data has been deleted  becomes nothing and causes error.

I could of course test for this, and may be I should, but I have a feeling that perhaps my adding code is in the wrong event?

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
            DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        End If
        For Each Grow As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
            Grow.Cells("ADJ").Value = Val(Grow.Cells("THAW1").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW2").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW3").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW4").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW5").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW6").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW7").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW8").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW9").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW10").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW11").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW12").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW13").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW14").Value.ToString) + Val(Grow.Cells("THAW15").Value.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Could someone suggest a better event to place the code into. May be its just a case of setting the cell state? Im not sure how that could be done.

Thank you

Comment: Take away the .tostring from all values being added up, so Val(Grow.Cells("THAW1").Value.ToString) should be Val(Grow.Cells("THAW1").Value). With all cells being empty I got an error with the tostring, but got 0 without the tostring.

Comment: taking out the tostring generates a null error if there is no number in the column, I could place "" in all the columns but I think that is just making a bad thing worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is most likely to check and adjust the value prior to the calculation.

```
If Grow.Cells("HAW1").Value Is Nothing OrElse Grow.Cells("HAW1").Value Is DBNull.Value Then Grow.Cells("HAW1").Value = ""
```